# How can I search any number after a certain words in Perl

Tags: perl

```
Changeset: 40042
User: xyz
Date: Friday, July 29, 2011 9:54:52 PM
```

Comment:

> [I#1326920] RINS Reference Data Maintenance Development completed. Added RINDefinition,RINEquivalence and RINObligati

Items:

```
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/application/common/ICTSDatabaseObjectMaps.java
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/application/client/controller/MainController.java
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminCache.java
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminManager.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINDefinition.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINEquivalence.java


Changeset: 40043
User: xyzx
Date: Friday, July 29, 2011 9:54:52 PM
```

Comment:

> [I#1326920] RINS Reference Data Maintenance Development completed. Added RINDefinition,RINEquivalence and RINObligati

Items:

```
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINObligation.java
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/Commodity.java
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/CommodityType.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/RINDefinition.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/RINEquivalence.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/RINObligation.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINDefinitionMap.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINDefinitionMap.xml
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINEquivalenceMap.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINEquivalenceMap.xml
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINObligationMap.java
add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/maps/RINObligationMap.xml
edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/trade/TradeLocalizedResources.java
```

Check-in Notes:

```
Code Reviewer:
Performance Reviewer:
Security Reviewer:
```

The above lines are in one array. I want to read it line by line and if any line contains `Changeset:` then get the number next to Changeset:
Please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

**Code from OP's comment:**

```
foreach(@loginfo){
    #print "$_\n";
    @rev = $_=~/^C(\d{1,})/g;
    #print "....@rev\n";
    push(@rev_value,@rev);
    print @rev_value,"\n";
}
```

Comment: @picnic4u Re: code, not logic: `\d{1,}` AKA `\d+`, but with less noise. Pushing a global temp array to another global temp array and immediately printing it is horrid. Either save it all to the end and print it, or just print it right away. And don't use *two* temp arrays.

Answer (score 1):

just use regexp - man perlre

```
foreach my $l(@lines) {
    if ($l =~ /Changeset:\s+?(\d+)/) {
         print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
$input = <<EOL;
  edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/application/common/ICTSDatabaseObjectMaps.java
  edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/application/client/controller/MainController.java
  edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminCache.java
  edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminManager.java
  add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINDefinition.java
  add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINEquivalence.java
`Changeset: 40043`
  edit $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminCache.java

`Changeset: 4294967295`
  add  $/S/B/F_RINS/Java/V3/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/model/commoditymarket/_RINEquivalence.java

`Changeset: 42949672951289312789398123987123`
EOL
foreach my $l(split(/\n/,$input)) {
    if ($l =~ /Changeset:\s+?(\d+)/) {
         print "number $1\n";
    }
}
```

outputs

```
number 40043
number 4294967295
number 42949672951289312789398123987123
```

Comment: i edited the post to demonstrate that it works. please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the lines in an array, you can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

```
use v5.10;
my @lines = map /^Changeset:\s*(\d+)/g, @array;
say for @lines;
```

Also works if you replace the array with a filehandle, e.g. `<$fh>` (or any list, for that matter).